# Insert/update based on dynamic XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have following XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Data>
    <Id>560f05b2-b215-4fea-9ac6-7f012fbca331</Id>   
    <Number>384D25334E04593B6DE9955E72F413F8A0A828FF</Number>
    <CurrentDate>2012-11-21T09:09:26+00:00</CurrentDate>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>9cff574b-59ea-4cbd-a2db-9ed02b6cc602</Id>  
    <Number>384D25334E04593B6DE9955E72F413F8A0A828FF</Number>
    <Location>Town</Location>
    <CurrentDate>2012-11-21T09:09:53+00:00</CurrentDate>
  </Data> 
</NewDataSet>
```

I'm trying to write a query that will inster new record or update existing one based on given xml. The problem is I cannot use predefined names of columns, becuase table straucture sometimes is changing. So the idea is to generate dynamic query and apply it. So far I've got following thing:

```
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;


    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @TableData xml
    DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime

    -- declare cursor
    DECLARE cursor_inserting CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
        r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)'), 
        r.query('.')
    FROM @Data.nodes('//NewDataSet/*') AS records(r)
    ORDER BY r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)')

    -- open cursor
    OPEN cursor_inserting
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_inserting INTO @TableName, @TableData

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        -- Get id
        SELECT @Id = o.value('Id[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') FROM @TableData.nodes('*') as n(o)
        SELECT @CurrentDate = o.value('CurrentDate[1]', 'datetime') FROM @TableData.nodes('*') as n(o)

        SET @Query = NULL

-- temporary update query
SET @UpdateTemp = NULL
SELECT @UpdateTemp = COALESCE(@UpdateTemp + ', ', '') + o.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') + ' = ''' + CAST(o.query('text()') as nvarchar(4000)) + '''' FROM @TableData.nodes('/*/*') as n(o)
SET @UpdateTemp = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @UpdateTemp + ' WHERE Id = ''' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(40)) + ''''

-- temporary insert query
SET @Insert1Temp = NULL
SELECT @Insert1Temp = COALESCE(@Insert1Temp + ', ', '') + o.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)')  FROM @TableData.nodes('/*/*') as n(o)

SET @Insert2Temp = NULL
SELECT @Insert2Temp = COALESCE(@Insert2Temp + ', ', '') + '''' + CAST(o.query('text()') as nvarchar(4000)) + ''''  FROM @TableData.nodes('/*/*') as n(o)

SET @InsertTemp = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName  + ' ( ' + @Insert1Temp + ' ) VALUES ( ' + @Insert2Temp + ' )'

IF @TableName = 'Data'
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Id = @Id)
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblAudit WHERE Id = @Id AND CurrentDate < @CurrentDate)
        BEGIN               
            SET @Query = @UpdateTemp            
        END

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Query = @InsertTemp
    END
END

IF @Query IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @Query
    EXEC (@Query)
END
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_inserting INTO  @TableName, @TableData
END

CLOSE cursor_inserting
DEALLOCATE cursor_inserting
```

If there is any better way to achive this inside SQL I would like to know, I know that I can do this outside SQL in my application code, but I would like to have it in one place in stored procedure to provide xml and have required action taken.

**UPDATE 1**

I would like to clarify that my main problem is query proper generation based on XML. The different way of handling instert/update is nice to see, but as addition

**UPDATE 2**

There can be more than 1 table in xml. E.g. not only Data but also Data2

**UPDATE 3**

I've update what I have now - and it is now generating proper Insert/Update however I now have issues with conversion. E.g. Date string is in xml format and sql doesn't want to convert it automaticaly. So my next step is get proper column type from database and instead of generate query instert directly from xml.I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use `MERGE` and SQL XQuery to do it in one statement.

Something like...

```
merge Data as target
using 
(
    select  
        x.q.value('Id[1]','uniqueidentifier') as ID,
        x.q.value('Number[1]','varchar(50)') as Number,
        x.q.value('Location[1]','varchar(50)') as Town,
        x.q.value('CurrentDate[1]','datetime') as CurrentDate
    from
        @TableData.nodes('/NewDataSet/Data')x(q)
) as Source (ID,Number,Town,CurrentDate)
    on target.id=source.id
when matched and target.CurrentDate < source.CurrentDate then
    update set 
         Number = source.number, 
         town = source.town, 
         currentdate = source.currentdate
when not matched then
    insert (ID,number,town,currentdate)
    values (source.id,source.number,source.town,source.currentdate);
```

Comment: it looks interesting the problem is with first part, it can happen I won't know the names of columns that will come in xml, since query won't change after DB structure does, and xml can contain column that is not in query. So I would need the first part dynamic

Comment: Also update/instert requires to know columns during wring a query, so it is not suitable for me.

Comment: @marcin you could generate the above SQL from your XML into a SQL string and execute it with `sp_executesql`

Comment: I agree, I just have problem with generating it :). That's why I created this question, how to generate columns and values